# error in sql query result while search with nodes

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, node.js, express

i have one query for search where i have string Ennemie d'état and if i search with key `Ennemie d'état` then it show data not found problem is in single quote (') my query is as below:

```
WHERE (
  post_tbl.title LIKE ('%${key.replace(/'/g, "''" )}%') or post_tbl.caption like ('%${key.replace( /'/g, "''" )}%') )
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? Have you heard about [Parameterized SQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/parameterizing-mysql-queries-in-node#:~:text=When%20we%20parameterize%20a%20database,command%20that%20should%20be%20executed.)?